# HyperLedger Fabric from IBM is fork of Tangle or Etherium?

Tags: ethereum, hyperledger

I read as if HL Fabric was the most interesting thing ever created on the use of blockchain, but when I read the documentation (very short) about Hyperledger Fabric I came across some coincidences.

the install is very common:
https://github.com/hyperledger/hyperledger

but the documentation mentions "tangle":
https://github.com/hyperledger

but the blog documentation:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ 
is equal Ether documentation:
https://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ether.html

Does anyone know of any tool that I can compare the code of 3?

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not related at all. The Hyperledger documentation is not short. The Hyperledger Github project does not mention Tangle as far as I can see. The only similarity with the [Hyperledger documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Etherium documentation](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/) is that they are hosted on [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.org/) and look similar, the content is completely different. Hyperledger, Tangle, and Etherium are developed completely independently.

Answer (score 0):

There is confusion here with the term `Hyperledger`.

Hyperledger is a Linux Foundation consortium of multiple open-source enterprise blockchain technologies (unrelated to Tangle). It includes:

- `Hyperledger Fabric`, contributed by IBM (and not a fork of anything)
- `Hyperledger Sawtooth`, contributed by Intel. Also not a fork. Both are Apache 2 licensed
- `Hyperledger Burrow` an Ethereum VM (EVM) compatible blockchain (also included in Sawtooth)
- other block chain technologies and tools

So you can see there is no forking--these are independent platforms with independent code bases (Fabric, Sawtooth, Burrow, Tangle, Ethereum).

The only relations are
- Ethereum and Burrow both implement EVM
- Hyperledger platforms are all under the Linux Foundation Hyperledger consortium, but are independent platforms and code bases.

Comment: Tangle is alternative distrubuted database design to Blockchain, it's got nothing to do with Hyperledger as far as I know.